# How does this Apollo Guidance Computer code work out sine and cosine?

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, trigonometry

This code is used for calculating sine and cosine, I guess, on the AGC, Apollo Guidance Computer. But I don't understand how it works.

https://github.com/chrislgarry/Apollo-11/blob/27e2acf88a6345e2b1064c8b006a154363937050/Luminary099/SINGLE_PRECISION_SUBROUTINES.agc

```
# SINGLE PRECISION SINE AND COSINE

        COUNT*  $$/INTER
SPCOS       AD  HALF        # ARGUMENTS SCALED AT PI
SPSIN       TS  TEMK
        TCF SPT
        CS  TEMK
SPT     DOUBLE
        TS  TEMK
        TCF POLLEY
        XCH TEMK
        INDEX   TEMK
        AD  LIMITS
        COM
        AD  TEMK
        TS  TEMK
        TCF POLLEY
        TCF ARG90
POLLEY      EXTEND
        MP  TEMK
        TS  SQ
        EXTEND
        MP  C5/2
        AD  C3/2
        EXTEND
        MP  SQ
        AD  C1/2
        EXTEND
        MP  TEMK
        DDOUBL
        TS  TEMK
        TC  Q
ARG90       INDEX   A
        CS  LIMITS
        TC  Q       # RESULT SCALED AT 1.
```

Comment: I don't know if this question, follow the community guidelines. Please help and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: IHave you done any searching on sine/cosine algorithms for assembly? It likely uses a simple algorithm based upon Taylor series expansion.

Comment: [Apollo Guidance Computer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apollo-guidance-computer) is the tag for apollo at retrocomputing, where they discuss ancient architectures.

Comment: @ErikEidt: I raised a custom flag to ask for it to be migrated to https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/, based on that and the fact that "explain this code to me" reverse engineering questions on SO are usually not encouraged here, but questions about how / why something was designed a certain way or how something worked are often welcomed on that site.

Comment: @lurker thank you, for the advice, i am trying to do so

Comment: @Peter Cordes is their something i have to do?

Comment: See accepted answer on [Space Exploration Stack Exchange](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/30955)